# Entity.Include() + local IIS development setup + Chrome = long browser requests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, google-chrome, iis-7.5, entity-framework-4.1

I have an ASP.NET MVC3 web application with EF Code First. It's set up to debug using my local IIS (as opposed to the Visual Studio 2010 Developer Server). I also have Google Chrome set as my default browser.

If my repository layer uses the .Include() method, Chrome takes at least 10 seconds to return the page, usually more than 30 seconds. I can step through the debugger all the way to the View very quickly, and yet Chrome still takes that long to finish serving the page.

This problem goes away if I do any of the following

Take out the .Include()

Use IE or Firefox

Use VS Development Server instead of local IIS

I have no idea why this would happen, or how to further troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the [Glimpse NuGet package](http://getglimpse.com/). I disabled it in my web.config and it works fine now.

Comment: Qntmfred - Glimpse, by default, tries to show you your viewMoldel. To do that we serialize the object, which sounds like in your case may be triggering database calls. If you pass a fully materialized VM to your view, Glimpse should add very little overhead.